# WPA2 Enterprise with TTLS and PAP on ubuntu-touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, wpa2

I am tyring to connect to a WPA2 enterprise wireless network (not eduroam) using my ubuntuphone. Under settings I can enter all the information (as before in android) but the button Connect stays greyed out. The network does not use CA certificates or an anonymous identity.
Has this not yet been implemented or is there a trick?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With the latest OTA 7 release (Ubuntu 15.04 r26) the button is functional.
You can also use a ssh connection via wifi to create a Network Manager Configuration file directly on the device.